# European Character Encoding Issue: Java + Jetty

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jetty, iso-8859-1

I've Spring JDK8 code(REST service) deployed over Jetty 9.4.44 version {the same issue with JDK7 & lower version of jetty } where I'm facing issue with European characters.Those are showing incorrect over server.
Data has saving correctly over DB(sql server).but when we see it over server its not correct.
Everything works fine locally but as soon we deploy the code to server its not working.
We have tried every other solution which converts data explicitly into UTF-8 technically,Also over server we've updated everywhere encoding standard to 'UTF-8'. But nothing helping out and it continue to show wrong data over server.

Actual character: ø |
Over server: Ã¸ |
at the receiving end: �

I guess something wrong with server settings but not getting what causing this exactly. Can someone please help out with this?
Thank you!!

Comment: By “sql server”, do you mean *Microsoft SQL Server*? If so, say so, as that might be important here.

Comment: Your Question is a bit vague. You should recreate the problem with an absolute minimum of code, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'ø'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'iso-8859-1')` returns `'Ã¸'`.

Comment: Try launching the java app with ```java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar file.jar```